# How to assign javascript value to liquid on shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I got the value of html radio button from javascript code and I want to assign that value to variable of shopify liquid code can I do that.

```html
<span id="selected_variant_title">{{ selected_variant_title }}</span>


<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      // Handle change event for radio buttons
      $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
        // Retrieve the selected value
        var proteinValue = $('input[name="meal_radio_input"]:checked').val();
        console.log("Test", $('input[name="meal_radio_input"]:checked').val());
        });
    });
    var selected_variant_title = '';

function handleRadioChange() {
  var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName('meal_radio_input');
  for (var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
    if (radioButtons[i].checked) {
      selected_variant_title = radioButtons[i].value;
      console.log('Selected value: ' + selected_variant_title);
      break;
    }
  }

  // Update the content of the selected_variant_title span element
  var selectedVariantTitleElement = document.getElementById('selected_variant_title');
  selectedVariantTitleElement.textContent = selected_variant_title;
}
```

I want assign selected_variant_title in a liquid veriable like as
{% assign protein_option = selected_variant_title %}

Answer (score 1):

As Liquid is a rendered side language you won't be able to do that.
To the contrary you may assign Liquid value to JS vars.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how we can include it as a variable in our data filtering?

Answer (score -1):

You cant do that as liquid code runs first and Javascript next,so you need to use javascript in this case completely.